# scipy.optimize.minimize: l2 norm constraints in matrix rows

Tags: optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize

I am interested to apply `l2` norm constraint in each row of the parameters matrix in `scipy.optimize.minimize`. What I have tried so far is

```
def l2_const(x):

    x = x.reshape(r, c)
    b = np.sqrt((x**2).sum(axis=1)) - 1
    return np.broadcast_to(b[:, None], (r, c)).flatten()


x0 = np.random.random((r, c))
const = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': l2_const},)
f_min = minimize(fun=cost, x0=x0, method='SLSQP', jac=gradient, constraints=const)
```

but the computed parameters `f_min.x` are all zeros. Does anyone know how to implement correctly this type of constraints?

**EDIT 1:** An example to apply this type of constraints can be found in my answer of my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765309/multi-class-logistic-regression-from-scratch/65789477#65789477).

**EDIT 2:**  Below you can find a complete working example. The results are very low when the constrains are used. Any suggestions are welcome.

**Class:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn import preprocessing

class myLR():

    def __init__(self, reltol=1e-8, maxit=1000, opt_method=None, verbose=True, seed=0):
        self.maxit = maxit
        self.reltol = reltol
        self.seed = seed
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.opt_method = opt_method

        self.lbin = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()

    def w_2d(self, w, n_classes):
        return np.reshape(w, (n_classes, -1))

    def softmax(self, W, X):
        a = np.exp(X @ W.T)
        o = a / np.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        return o

    def squared_norm(self, x):
        x = np.ravel(x, order='K')
        return np.dot(x, x)

    def cost(self, W, X, T, n_samples, n_classes):
        W = self.w_2d(W, n_classes)
        log_O = np.log(self.softmax(W, X))
        c = -(T * log_O).sum()
        return c / n_samples

    def gradient(self, W, X, T, n_samples, n_classes):
        W = self.w_2d(W, n_classes)
        O = self.softmax(W, X)
        grad = -(T - O).T.dot(X)
        return grad.ravel() / n_samples

    def l1_constraint(self, x, n_classes, n_features):

        x = x.reshape(n_classes, -1)
        b = x.sum(axis=1) - 1
        return np.broadcast_to(b[:, None], (n_classes, n_features)).flatten()

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        n_classes = len(np.unique(y))
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape

        if n_classes == 2:
            T = np.zeros((n_samples, n_classes), dtype=np.float64)
            for i, cls in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
                T[y == cls, i] = 1
        else:
            T = self.lbin.fit_transform(y)

        np.random.seed(self.seed)
        W_0 = np.random.random((n_classes, n_features))

        const = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': self.l1_constraint, 'args': (n_classes, n_features,)},)
        options = {'disp': self.verbose, 'maxiter': self.maxit}
        f_min = minimize(fun=self.cost, x0=W_0,
                         args=(X, T, n_samples, n_classes),
                         method=self.opt_method,
                         constraints=const,
                         jac=self.gradient,
                         options=options)

        self.coef_ = self.w_2d(f_min.x, n_classes)
        self.W_ = self.coef_

        return self

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        O = self.softmax(self.W_, X)
        return O

    def predict(self, X):
        sigma = self.predict_proba(X)
        y_pred = np.argmax(sigma, axis=1)
        return y_pred
```

**Main:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from myLR import myLR

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, 0:2]
y = iris.target

par_dict2 = {'reltol': 1e-6,
            'maxit': 20000,
            'verbose': 20,
            'seed': 0}

# Create different classifiers.
classifiers = {
    'myLR': myLR(**par_dict2),
}

n_classifiers = len(classifiers)

plt.figure(figsize=(3 * 2, n_classifiers * 2))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.2, top=.95)

xx = np.linspace(3, 9, 100)
yy = np.linspace(1, 5, 100).T
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
Xfull = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
accuracy_score
for index, (name, classifier) in enumerate(classifiers.items()):
    classifier.fit(X, y)

    coef_ = classifier.coef_
    print(np.linalg.norm(coef_, axis=1))

    y_pred = classifier.predict(X)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y, y_pred)
    print("Accuracy (train) for %s: %0.1f%% " % (name, accuracy * 100))

    # View probabilities:
    probas = classifier.predict_proba(Xfull)
    n_classes = np.unique(y_pred).size
    for k in range(n_classes):
        plt.subplot(n_classifiers, n_classes, index * n_classes + k + 1)
        plt.title("Class %d" % k)
        if k == 0:
            plt.ylabel(name)
        imshow_handle = plt.imshow(probas[:, k].reshape((100, 100)),
                                   extent=(3, 9, 1, 5), origin='lower')
        plt.xticks(())
        plt.yticks(())
        idx = (y_pred == k)
        if idx.any():
            plt.scatter(X[idx, 0], X[idx, 1], marker='o', c='w', edgecolor='k')

ax = plt.axes([0.15, 0.04, 0.7, 0.05])
plt.title("Probability")
plt.colorbar(imshow_handle, cax=ax, orientation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

**EDIT 3:** I replaced the constraints, with

```
def l1_constraint(self, x, n_classes, n_features):
    
            x = x.reshape(n_classes, -1)
            b = x.sum(axis=1) - 1
            return b
```

It produces better results. However, the computed components `x1` and `x2` do not sum to 1? Is that fine?

Comment: This constraint is non-convex. To find globally optimal solutions you need a global solver.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thanks for the comment. I am having the same problem if I impose the sum of each row to equal one, i.e., if `b = x.sum(axis=1) - 1` in the constraint function. I thing this constraint is convex. Is something wrong with how the constraints are constructed?

Comment: The code is incomplete so we cannot reproduce things. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen please see my edit if you are interested.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen in you first comment, you mentioned that we need a global optimizer for the `l2` constraint. Is it equivalent to use `||x||_2<=1` (`ineq`) in order to avoid the global optimizer?

Comment: I don't know if that makes the model convex: I would need to understand the objective. There is only a blob of code, no mathematical model, so that is a difficult task. We need to reverse-engineer the mathematical model. I know, however: any nonlinear equality constraint is non-convex.